# How do I Format a String Date in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Using Report Builder,
In a Matrix for a report I'm creating:
I have dates in my data the are are "FullMonthName-Year"
I am trying to get them to a report as "AbbreviatedMonthName-Year"

Example:

'January-2020' turns into 'Jan-2020'
'February-2021' turns into 'Feb-2021'

thanks in advance

Within the Text-Box Properties, I have been trying to mess with the Format function but can't seem to get it right.
ex:
=Format(Fields!labelDt.Value, "MM-YYYY") just gives me "MM-YYYY"

Comment: Doesn't sound like the original field is of type `date` or `datetime`. Is it getting formatted to `FullMonthName-Year` in the view or stored procedure that your report is consuming?

Comment: ah - you are totally right. It's an nvarchar.

Comment: Cheers @AlwaysLearning - your comment helped me figure it!
I used a Left(x, 3) function to get the first three letters of the Month, then concatenated the rest of the string date with a Right(y, 5) function.
Cheers!

Comment: The problem is you aren't storing dates but strings. You can't change the format of a string because it's already a string; the value `'I like apples'` doesn't make sense to be "formatted" as `MMM yyyy`. If you want to be able to format your dates you should first start by storing your dates as a `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending your value type you can use formatting for dates and expression for strings

For dates you can set the format string to `"MMM-yyyy"`

For strings you can use the expression

`=Left(Fields!labelDt.Value,3) & "-" & Right(Fields!labelDt.Value,4)`

[image]